# PHP: xpath not working on php5.3 because of unexpected "["

Tags: php, xpath, php-5.3

I was running the following line on PHP5.4 without any problem:

```
$lstContent = $data->xpath("/response/lst[@name='highlighting']")[0]->lst[$i]->arr->str;
```

But now on PHP5.3 (production system) I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/html/upload/inc_suche_code.php on line 153

Any ideas for a quick fix?
Updating PHP won't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In older versions of PHP you can not access array values directly on variables that are the result of a function. You have to split up the expression using a temporary variable.

```
$result = $data->xpath("/response/lst[@name='highlighting']");
$lstContent = $result[0]->lst[$i]->arr->str;
```

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Edit: Obligatory "you should also consider upgrading your PHP version". This annoying limitation was fixed ages ago, not to mention that the 5.3 had its [end of life in 2014](http://php.net/eol.php), meaning it has not received security upgrades since.

Comment: I know this is not a good thing but I really have to say this most funniest and a unique name I saw in OS. nice!

Comment: @Sand   ha ha ha.lol

Comment: Haha @Sand. Thank you :)